# Need help in putting jquery inside php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, modal-dialog

I have this php lines and a jquery script inside it. But the script is not working even if I try this one.

```
<?php session_start();
        $session_id = session_id();

        if (isset($_GET['cart'])){
            //echo "<script>alert ('try');</script>";
            echo "<script>";
            echo "$(document).ready(function(){";
            echo "$('#cartModal').modal('show');";
            echo "});";
            echo "</script>";
        }
    ?>
```

the id `cartModal` of a modal is present. I want to trigger or show the modal when the `$_GET['cart']` is set. How could I do that?

Comment: Does your page submit to itself (causing a refresh) when you set the cart param?

Comment: kinda.. but it's actually submitting data to another php file then I use `window.location` and return to the main page to trigger the modal by passing `true` valuse to link id `cart`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget you need to put that jquery inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

After all that code needs to be called by something.

So your final code would look like:

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale-1.0">
        <title>Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
        <?php session_start();
            $session_id = session_id();

            if (isset($_GET['cart'])){
                echo "<script>$(document).ready(function(){$('#cartModal').modal(show);});</script>";
            }
        ?>
</head>
```

There is one more trivial thing...

You need to make sure you are actually including jquery in your head, otherwise it won't work!

Comment: Your advice about adding the jquery in the head solved my problem. but your suggested code `echo "<script>$(document).ready(function(){$('#cartModal').modal(show);});</script>";` is kinda glitch. But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Without further information, I speculate that the javascript is executed before the page could fully load. You need to wrap your javascript with $(document).ready(function() {}) as such

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#cartModal').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: Please be little more descriptive with your title next time, it will help all of us :)